# Autofac and Generic Typed Factory like Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, autofac, typed-factory-facility

In the current project I am working with **Autofac** but usually I use **Castle Windsor**, so I am trying to understand how I can resolve the *typed factory* pattern available in Castle Windsor, by using Autofac.

I have the following Query and Query Handler contract:

```
public interface IQuery<out TResult>
{

}

public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

Each contract has multiple implementations, so for each `IQuery<result>` there is a corresponding `IQueryHandler<IQuery<result>, result>` implementation.

I am registering all using this fluent approach:

```
public class CqrsModule : Module
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // prepare all assemblies for IoC
        var assemblies = new[]
        {
            typeof(IQuery<>).Assembly,
            typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).Assembly,
            typeof(IBus).Assembly
        };

        // autofac regisration
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IQuery<>))
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IBus));
    }
}
```

But I have a problem. From my Bus I do not want to be aware of the existing Handlers, so I use a **Typed Factory** as following:

```
public interface IQueryFactory
{
    IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> BuildHandler<TQuery, TResult>() 
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
}
```

But I have no idea how I can register this **Typed Factory** using Autofac. In Castle Windsor I would simply do:

```
kernel.Register(
    Component.For<IQueryFactory>()
        .AsFactory()
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the answer is no, because Autofac does not have such a concept of **Typed Factory**.

The alternative is to keep the contract and just create an implementation of it for the specific case scenario which is *Use typed factory in Autofac*.

```
public sealed class AutofacQueryFactory : IQueryFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope scope;

    public AutofacQueryFactory(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    /// <see cref="IQueryFactory" />
    public IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> BuildHandler<TQuery, TResult>() where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    {
        return this.scope.Resolve<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>();
    }
}
```

**Note**
You should inject `ILifetimeScope`and not `IContainer` according to Autofac documentation.